# Is it possible to automate applications on virtual desktop using software like QTP?

Tags: automation, virtual, desktop, qtp

I am not speaking on virtual machines,but Virtual desktops. Softwares like [Desktops](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/desktops) from microsoft provide functionality to create virtual screens and group windows onto them.

Is is possible to use Automation software like QTP on some application in one desktop and have other programs run in other desktops ?

Will the automation run ? without hindering other desktops ?

Is there any other technique to do this ?

Comment: Like a distributed desktop environment??

Comment: Are you talking about Citrix or RDP?

Comment: i am not talking about citrix or rdp . The desktop software i am talking about is here ,http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc817881 . It allows us to create virtual desktops.

What i am asking is , is it possible to run application under test and qtp in one virtual desktop,and use windows word on the other?

if we can do this , it saves a lot of machine resources at my place.

Comment: That's a good question, what I do is use [Virtual Box](http://www.virtualbox.org/) for running QTP. Why don't you try the virtual desktop way and let us know how it came out?

Comment: Thank you Motti . That is a nice way as you have said . But its an intensive solution but a practically possible one . Especially if you own a server .

Comment: Motti,I tried it with Virtual desktop from http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc817881 . its not working. only one desktop seems to be active . If i run qtp in one desktop and move to other , qtp throws an error :(  .

Comment: @Deepan sorry to hear about the virtual desktop, what error does it throw? As for the virtual box solution, I run one on a two year old laptop. You don't need a particularly strong machine. The only drawback is that you need another license of windows.

Comment: @Motti, The error is the usual window not found or parent not found kind. I bet if they make qtp work with virtual desktop , we can have a huge ROI .

Answer (score 1):

A co-worker had a look and it appears that QTP **does** work on virtual desktops, however when the virtual desktop isn't active it's like a minimized RDP session and steps that depend on device replay don't work (see [my answer regarding RDP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486079/execution-of-qtp-scripts-on-remote-machines/6486397#6486397)).

If you want to work on other things while running tests, the simple solution would be to run a virtual machine (some are free e.g. [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/)), machines nowadays are strong enough to power a VM and still work as usual on the physical machine.